# How to call a list subset with a "character" object in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to loop this:

```
library(demography)
fr.mort$rate$male
fr.mort$rate$female
fr.mort$rate$total
```

in order to get something like this:

```
library(demography)
for (i in c("male", "female", "total")) {
  get(paste("fr.mort$rate$", i, sep = ""))
}
```

But it doen't work. I don't get why "get" doesn't work in this case :)

Help me please!

Comment: get "returns the value of a named object" so it is looking for objects called "fr.mort$rate$male" in your global environment and not finding them. what is your desired result and why are you trying this method? maybe you are looking for the eval, parse method? `eval(parse(text = 'fr.mort$rate$male'))`

Comment: You should really never use `get()`. There is almost always a better way. `for (i in c("male", "female", "total")) {fr[["mort"]][["rate"]][[i]]}` would do the same thing, although in this case that "thing" is nothing. `get()` is meant to extract a varible with a character vector. In this example `fr.mort` is the variable. `rate` is not a variable nor is `male`, `female`, or `total`. `get` does not allow to do indexing as you are trying to do. It is simply a character -> symbol lookup. Only `get("fr.mort")` would be expected to work.

Comment: rawr, thanks it works. MrFlick, this is what I actually needed for the original non-simplified example, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much easier, safer ways to subset a list. Try it with `[` subsetting. R's vectorized subsetting makes getting list elements easy. Here's an example with a nested list, `dat`.

```
> dat <- list(x = setNames(list(1,2,3,4,5), letters[1:5])
> dat$x[c("a", "c", "e")]
# $a
# [1] 1
#
# $c
# [1] 3
#
# $e
# [1] 5
```

In your code, this would be

```
> library(demography)
> fr.mort$rate[c("male", "female", "total")]
```

I'm quite sure most seasoned R users would recommend you do this instead.